# Linq query "specific cast is not valid"

Tags: c#, linq-to-dataset

Following **Linq to datatable** query gives me error **Specific cast is not valid**.

```
decimal[] temp = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => new
       {
           totLen = r.Field<decimal>("Quantity") 
                     * (r.Field<decimal>("Breath") 
                         * r.Field<decimal>("Length"))
       })
    .Cast<decimal>()
    .ToArray();
```

Can any one suggest me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create anonymous type:

```
decimal[] temp = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => r.Field<int>("Quantity") 
               * r.Field<decimal>("Breath") 
               * r.Field<decimal>("Length"))
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just return a `decimal` straight from `Select()`.

```
decimal[] temp = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(
    r => r.Field<decimal>("Quantity") * (r.Field<decimal>("Breath") * r.Field<decimal>("Length")
)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Additional brackets and casting is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to cast anonymous type to decimal, which of course will not work. Do not create anonymous type - simply select decimal value:

```
decimal[] temp = (from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
                  select r.Field<decimal>("Quantity") * 
                         r.Field<decimal>("Breath") * 
                         r.Field<decimal>("Length")).ToArray();
```

Same with Linq methods syntax:

```
decimal[] temp = dt.AsEnumerable()
                   .Select(r => r.Field<decimal>("Quantity") * 
                                r.Field<decimal>("Breath") * 
                                r.Field<decimal>("Length"))
                   .ToArray();
```

How to make your code work? Use `Select` instead of `Cast`:

```
.Select(x => x.totLen).ToArray();
```

But again, you don't need anonymous type to select single value.

Answer (score 0):

Your projection (`Select`) creates instances of anonymous type like this:

```
class SomeAnonymousClass
{
   public totLen { get; set; }
}
```

...which instances can't be casted to decimal.

Comment: @SagarUpadhyay: if so, why are you creating anonymous type?